# How to implement ping request in C language for Windows platform?

Tags: c

I want to implement ping request in C language. I am working on Windows platform. Can any one suggest how to implement it or if code is already available then from where I can find it?

Comment: @aJ, it would be polite to actually ask if it was homework first before retagging :-)

Comment: @PAx, I didn't know this. I shall revert back.

Comment: Actualy i found code for ping on the net, but it is dependent on Linux environment.I want code for Windows platform.

Comment: @Ashish, if Linux versions are all that are available, you may have to convert them. Or simply use Cygwin to recompile to a Windows executable.

Comment: Thanks for your help.now i am using Cygwin to run that code.but when i run this i am getting "operation not permitted" messages.To run that code should i do some settings in my firewal or anythin else?
kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

Highly useful and open source - [fping](http://fping.sourceforge.net/).

> fping is a ping(1) like program which uses the Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) echo request to determine if a host is up. fping is different from ping in that you can specify any number of hosts on the command line, or specify a file containing the lists of hosts to ping. Instead of trying one host until it timeouts or replies, fping will send out a ping packet and move on to the next host in a round-robin fashion. If a host replies, it is noted and removed from the list of hosts to check. If a host does not respond within a certain time limit and/or retry limit it will be considered unreachable.
>
> Unlike ping, fping is meant to be used in scripts and its output is easy to parse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use system() to run command line instructions. So something like

```
system("ping 127.0.0.1")
```

should work.

Comment: No, system() works anywhere. And Windows does have a ping executable.

Comment: That i can do but actually i want to store  average round trip time, which comes after executing ping request through system(), in database.Invoking system() how can i get that round trip time?